# Modulo large prime - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, largenumber

I am trying to partition a large string F to m blocks as follows:

```
import random
from largeprimes import generateRandom

def generateRandom(length):
    t = random.randint(0, 2**length)
    str = "{0:b}".format(t)
    if (len(str) < length):
        str.zfill(length)
    return str

def divide_file_block (): #return bi: int
    b = []
    for i in range (0, m):
        b_i = F[(i*blocklen) : ((i+1)* blocklen)]
        temp = int(b_i, 2) % q
        b.append(temp)
    return b

F = generateRandom(102400)
m = 100
blocklen = len(F)/m
q = generateLargePrime(1024) # generateLargePrime is from https://langui.sh/2009/03/07/generating-very-large-primes/
print divide_file_block ()
```

Note: you shall copy the code from [1](https://langui.sh/2009/03/07/generating-very-large-primes/) to the current directory, remove the last `print` statement there and name it `largpeprimes.py`. This makes the `generateLargePrime` function importable.

When I test on a small example, it printed out correct result. But when I test on b_i and q having 1024 bits, it printed out the error:

```
temp = int(b_i, 2) % q

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'
```

Could you please explain me why and give me a suggestion to show this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `q` coming from? The error messages suggests it's a `str` instead of an `int`.

Comment: @dano: Hi dano, q is a large prime (1024 bits)

Comment: I give a example of q here so that you can easily consider 172109439245336032900147786262085741056980731214266260394679478998361937814056070968128730536720050876062418961169716552859563594132652901849835758641549198220264323981501227073112626661755177484807307362559530134807213757494011761190239378171051397527989789638065062299409871547682671113803209638862748463141

Comment: The result of q I get from the following code: https://langui.sh/2009/03/07/generating-very-large-primes/

Comment: `q` is a string, not an integer, and strings can't be prime.  The result of `generateLargePrime` from the code you linked is an integer, not a string, so you probably didn't do `q = generateLargePrime(1024)`.  Which takes us back to dano's original question: where is `q` coming from?

Comment: @DSM: I actually did q = generateLargePrime(1024)

Comment: @santa: you may have typed that at one point.  That is not where your `q` is coming from.

Comment: @DSM: I firstly defined q as a global variable. Then, I call q = generateLargePrime(1024), then I run the function as above

Comment: @santa What about minimal working example. Something like `q = 1721....141` then `b_i = "1001000101"` and finally `int(b_i, 2) % q`.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky: If 1 of 2 operands is small, it is OK. But if b_i and q are both large, the error happens

Comment: @santa Good. Can you show it in short working example? Provide minimal, complete and verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JanVlcinsky: Thank you. Firstly, I generate F as 102400 bits using F = random.randint(0, 2**102400). I let m = 100 and blocklen = |F|/m = 1024. Then, I generate q = generateLargePrime(1024); and perform the above function

Comment: @JanVlcinsky: sometimes, random.randint only gives a value which is less than 102400 bits, I just simply padding '0' in the beginning using F.zfill (102400)

Comment: @santa If you would read the link describing minimal, complete verifiable example, you would find, that the `random.random` is out of scope. The problem is not with `random`, but with some values (which you should show) surprising you with unexpected exception. Btw, the example is best, if used within your question, there is is most readable. It is fine to edit your question. Comments are difficult to read when used for piece of code.

Comment: `generateLargePrime()` might have returned `Failure after ... tries.` (instead of raising an exception. That is very bad style...) and you go on working with that, thinking you had a value, but have only that weird string. It might help to `print q` at the appropriate place to see what you really have.

Comment: @glglgl: thank you. i understand the reason now and have fixed it

Comment: @santa I edited your question to be closer to Minimal Complete Verifiable Example just to show, how it could looks like. Ideally, it would contain all the code without instructions to download the code from external url, but it would make the question a bit too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The function `generateLargePrime` sometime returns string

Trying the code I run into the same problem.

Testing it in debugger I got the cause: `q` has a value of `'Failure after 1100.0 tries.'

This is definitely a string an causes the failures.

I would recommend modifying the `generateLargePrime` code to throw an exception instead of reporting the failure by returned value.

## Few tips for detecting this kind of problems

### print out the problematic value

This is the simplest (and probably most popular) quick solution.

something like

```
b_i = F[(i*blocklen) : ((i+1)* blocklen)]
print "q", q # here is all the magic
temp = int(b_i, 2) % q
```

would tell you the value

### place `assert` into your code

```
b_i = F[(i*blocklen) : ((i+1)* blocklen)]
assert isinstance(q, int)
temp = int(b_i, 2) % q
```

would throw an exception as soon as `q` is not of type `int`

### run the code in debugger

`pdb` comes with Python, I prefer `ipdb` which comes with IPython, both would help you.

1. have the failing code written as a script
2. Try to run it via Python interpreter

   $ python failingscript.py
3. as it fails, you simply try once more, but instead of `python` use `pdb` or `ipdb`

   $ ipdb failingscript.py
4. the debugger let you control running the code line by line. Usually I let it run by "c" (continue) command and it soon crashes at the problematic point. Then I use "l" (list) to see, what line of code we are at, and finally use "p" (print) command to print values of variables, which are making problems. This way I used "p q" and found, it is a string.

It takes a moment to learn `pdb` or `ipdb`, but it works as turbo resolver so it is definitely the skill to learn. Great tutorial is at [PMotW](http://pymotw.com/2/pdb/)

Comment: Thank you. I understand the reason now

Comment: @santa I have added few hints for debugging this style of problems.